# iOS sending push notifications to more devices at once PHP

Tags: php, ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have database with device tokens and php script, which can send notification to ios devices, but I need help how to send the same message to all of device tokens in my database? This is my php code:

```
<?
$con0 = mysql_connect("server","usr","pass");
mysql_select_db("table", $con0);   
//$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM token ORDER BY token");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM toke ORDER BY token");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $token=$row['token'];
}
mysql_close();



if($_POST['message']){

    $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);

    $payload = '{
                    "aps" : 

                        { "alert" : "'.$message.'",
                          "badge" : 1,
                          "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
                        } 
                }';

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'iphonista');
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
    if(!$fp){
        print "Failed to connect $err $errstrn";
        return;
    } else {
        print "Notifikace byla odeslána! <br><br><br>";
    }




        $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $token)) . pack      ("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        fwrite($fp, $msg);  

    fclose($fp);
}

?>
```

Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are on the good path. You just need to iterate to create a message per user.